# Latest Vulnerability Information for IT Security Research

Tags: research

Are there any web sites where one can visit to see the latest disclosed vulnerabilities in order to further develop IT security research skills and keep up-to-date?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, plenty.

One of the most prominent is [the Full Disclosure list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_disclosure_(mailing_list)), which was closed down in 2014 and then reborn.  You can find the past archives and subscription info at http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/ .

Another good source of general information are Linux distros' security lists, which provide announcements of fixed vulnerabilities in their software.  A small selection:

- [Ubuntu](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-security-announce)
- [Debian](https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/)
- [CentOS](https://lists.centos.org/mailman/listinfo/centos-announce)

MITRE [provides some feeds of CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/data_updates.html).

Answer (score 1):

Generally Twitter is a very useful resource for both vulnerabilities and general infosec news.  Specifically who is going to be need specific.

Team Cymru's blog is a good resource.

https://www.exploit-db.com/ is good for finding POCs for exploits

This is likely the most comprehensive of officially disclosed vulns: https://nvd.nist.gov/

Ultimately, if you want actionable resource for an enterprise that doesn't consume your time analyzing you are going to need to pay for a service.